# when i run the below mentioned code it gives me error that is pixels is not defined

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pixel

NameError: name 'pixels' is not defined

from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2

model = MTCNN()

## detect face in the image

faces = model.detect_faces(pixels)

## extract details of the face

x1, y1, width, height = faces[0]['box']

Answer (score 0):

following error is shown when above mentioned code is run